# Corsair K70: Adjusting keyboard brightness triggers chrome reload

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard

I am using a Corsair K70 (single colour backlit) on Ubuntu 14.04. If I cycle through the brightness setting (`off`, `dim`, `normal`, `bright`), transitioning from `off` -> `dim` caused calculator to open, and `bright` -> `off` causes a reload page (e.g., in Chrome).

I am mostly interested in why this is? Is it a fault with the design? How can I monitor exactly what key signals are being sent to the computer? But also, how can this behaviour be disabled?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with my new K70 I got today.

The solution was to install the unofficial (because Linux isn't supported officially) driver, [ckb](https://github.com/ccMSC/ckb), It's working great!

I also noticed that the lights for numlock and capslock started responding correctly after installing the driver.

Comment: This is really confusing.  Can you clean this up so that it just shows the actual solution?  Thanks.